# how to force download with browsers native downloader and deny 3rd party internet download manager tools

Tags: httpwebrequest, download, content-disposition

We know that "Content-Disposition" http header will force client to download manually. But if any 3rd party download manager such as IDM was installed on the client it intercepts the web requests and disallows some cookies. Can I block these tools and force the browser's native download manager for a specific download?

Comment: Probably going to be difficult if not impossible as a lot of those tools have specific modes to hide themselves such a spoofing user agents etc

Comment: also as long as you only allow someone to download one thing at a time (if thats what your trying to achieve) does it really matter how they download it

Comment: The file to download is an excel file of a calculation result. I'd like to show a "please wait" layer during downloading. Javascript waits a cookie that is sent from the UI server and closes the "wait" layer. But if IDM intercepts javascript couldn't get this cookie, just wait and check continuously.